# Getting Error while running npm run dev-server on windows 10

Tags: javascript, npm, apache-superset

I am trying to run dev-server for superset-frontend. I am getting the following error.
Any help would be highly appreciable.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://github.com/mzgoddard/jest-webpack/issues/27). Try to add

```sh
"webpack-cli":"^3.3.12"
```

in your package.json file.

Comment: I have same webpack-cli version.

Comment: @Gorakhnathnigam what is your version of webpack (run webpack --version)?

Comment: webpack --version is throwing error. I looked into package.json and its version is "webpack": "^4.42.0"

Comment: @Gorakhnathnigam maybe reinstall Webpack package by deleting your node_modules folder.